# Output of unknown method foo

Tags: java, output

What is the output of this code? Using it to study for an exam coming up soon:

```
public void print(int[] nums)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
        System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
    System.out.println("\n");
}

public void foo(int[] nums)
{
    this.print(nums);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (nums.length - 1); ++j)
            if (nums[j] > nums[j + 1])
            {
                int tmp = nums[j];
                nums[j] = nums[j + 1];
                nums[j+ 1] = tmp;
            }
        System.out.print(i + ": ");
        this.print(nums);
    }
}
```

---

using this input:

```
int[] nums = {9, 5, 8, 4, 2, 7, 3, 6, 1};

foo(nums);
```

tried to run it myself, couldn't get it to compile kept receiving a "can not find method foo" error.

Comment: If you format and indent your code, you will see the issue immediately.

Comment: @leppie ive tried everything even rewriting it, this is a last resort for help

Comment: I couldn't find a main class in your code!!! Probably that is the source of error here...

Comment: OK, perhaps the issue is not in the formatting. Can you show where the entire method where you calling the `input` from?

Comment: thats all I was given, everything I have is already posted. My best guess is that the input goes into the main method and is somehow executed. I am stuck

Comment: The foo method is not static method. Maybe that's the error.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see start point in your code example so sure you cannot see any output in your IDE console :) Just create class lets call it "ATest",  add main method and constructor as

```
ATest(){
foo(nums);
}

public static void main(String [] args){new ATest();}
```

...*you cannot invoke foo method directly from main method cause foo method is not-static*...

But please do read more tutorials next time

Goog luck

Answer (score 0):

You need a main method, an entry point to the program.

Also encapsulate the foo method in a class to be able to call it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       int[] nums = {9, 5, 8, 4, 2, 7, 3, 6, 1};

       foo(nums);

    }
```

So your final will look as this:

```
public class Test{

public Test()
{

}

public void print(int[] nums)

{

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
               System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
       System.out.println("\n");
}

public void foo(int[] nums)
{
      this.print(nums);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < (nums.length - 1); ++j)
                   if (nums[j] > nums[j + 1])
                     {
                          int tmp = nums[j];
                          nums[j] = nums[j + 1];
                          nums[j+ 1] = tmp;
                       }
           System.out.print(i + ": ");
           this.print(nums);
         }

      }

public static void main(String[] args)
        {
           int[] nums = {9, 5, 8, 4, 2, 7, 3, 6, 1};
           Test t = new Test();
           test.foo(nums);

        }


}
```